# how to filter for standard deviation within a pipeine

Tags: r, tidyverse

Is there an efficient way to filter out numbers say under 2.5 std. deviation within a pipeline?
I currently, calculate the std. dev value outside the pipe and then filter using this in the pipe. 
I'm sure there must be a more efficient way to accomplish this.

```
set.seed(125)
nd <- data.frame( x = rnorm(1000, 3, .1))
```

My current method

```
sdx <- sd(nd$x) * 2.5 + mean(nd$x)
sdx1 <- sd(nd$x) * -2.5 + mean(nd$x)


library(tidyverse)
nd %>% filter(x < sdx, x > sdx1) %>% .$x %>% hist
```

Comment: Try with `between` `nd %>% filter(between(x, sd(x) * -2.5 + mean(x), sd(x) * 2.5 + mean(x)))`

Comment: @akrun my question is around calculating the sd outside of the pipe. Is there a function that like `filter(x between(sd(2.5))`? SQL has something similar

Comment: @akrun ok got it. Could you post as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rearrange your equation with an `abs()` to simplify and only use `sd()` once:

```
... %>%
  filter(abs(x - mean(x)) < 2.5 * sd(x))

# or use the built-in `scale()` function
... %>% 
  filter(abs(scale(x)) < 2.5)

# or, as in comments, use between
... %>%
  filter(between(x, x - 2.5 * sd(x), x + 2.5 * sd(x)))

# or some between instead of abs()
... %>% 
  filter(between(scale(x), -2.5, 2.5))
```